# typography templates or good practice

Tags: css, templates, typography

Typography is one of the things that I can never get right when I design the web pages in css, the headings and body text never looks and feels as good as most other websites I see on the web. By this I main that my typography does not feel as readable and spacious as on these websites

I do try to copy the css of these nice looking websites, but I never seem to get the same result (or at lest I never seem to make those techniques my own, so that I can use them in the future). Plus, when it comes to typography, my css is all over the place; if I need to change the style later on, I spend a long time searching for the relevant value

When I first started learning css, I found a lot of tutorials on how to get the page layout correct (static, fluid, navigation left/right) but I never found any thing useful on how to get the right look and feel when it came to typography.
on the other hand there are a lot of book on typography but the don't seem to help on how to get typography looking good on the web.

I am hoping you can suggest some resources, or any fixed approaches that would always guaranty that type will look good on the web

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may be useful: http://ilovetypography.com/2008/02/28/a-guide-to-web-typography/

You're already doing the right thing by poking around the sites you admire and trying out their css; it's one of the best ways to learn.

In general, when I'm working with typography, the best things you can do to make it look good is to consider three things: contrast, color, and visual hierarchy.

- **Contrast**: If your text is presented on a background with a color that does not contrast it well, it's going to look bad. So bad, in fact, that it may be deemed 'inaccessible'. You can use a tool such as [Colour Contrast Check](http://www.snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html) to make sure your text complies with [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast).
- **Color**: You'll probably find that most of the site you enjoy don't have truly black text. Pure black isn't commonly found in nature, and black text on a white background is the highest contrast you can get, which can look a little harsh. Most sites tone it down by making their black text slightly gray, with css such as `color: rgb(30,30,30);`
  If you want to use colors, try to pick ones that work well together using [basic color theory](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/an-introduction-to-color-theory-for-web-designers/). Either that, or pick a nice dark color and stick with black.
- **Visual Hierarchy**: Basically, use bigger fonts for more important headlines. So an `h1` will most likely be your biggest piece of text, with each size going down all the way to `h6`, and anything else in `p` tags should be roughly the size of the text you see here. Webdesign Tuts just recently posted [an article on visual hierarchy](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/understanding-visual-hierarchy-in-web-design/) that was pretty good.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I found this link http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AsK4MoYiBVMldE12V3FJYk95YVRUZ18xNDJNOVRrSHc&hl=de#gid=0 an analysis of typography from most popular websites, it might help someone